# How to create pdf file from oracle database using PHP

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, pdf

How do I generate a pdf file from a database in PHP with codeigniter? I've tried searching on the internet but most are difficult to convert. And I'm using a oracle sql.

Comment: Some commands in mysql is different in oracle. I hope that you understand why I posted this.

Comment: How about generating the extract to HTML, then converting that to PDF? There are some open source PDF converters for PHP (e.g. pdflib).